# itextpdf different margin on specific page

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext

Good day everyone!

I have some questions regarding document:

1. Does itextpdf have the option to have a different margin on a specific page? I have tried to use

> document.setMargin

then

> document.newPage

but it seems that every page get the same margin.

2. Is there any way to prevent header and element from overlapping?

Thanks!

> EDIT

Here is the method that adds the document content:

```
    @Override
    void addDocumentContent(Document doc, PdfWriter writer, AbstractDiplomaDataModel diplomaData) throws DiplomaPdfFileProducerException {
        try {
            doc.setMargins(DefaultPdfDocumentSettings.LEFT_MARGIN, DefaultPdfDocumentSettings.RIGHT_MARGIN, 0f, 0f);
            doc.newPage();          
            doc.add(new DiplomaPdfDataGenerator(diplomaData).generateFirstPagePdf());
            doc.setMargins(DefaultPdfDocumentSettings.LEFT_MARGIN, DefaultPdfDocumentSettings.RIGHT_MARGIN, DefaultPdfDocumentSettings.TOP_MARGIN,DefaultPdfDocumentSettings.BOTTOM_MARGIN);
            doc.newPage();          
            doc.add(new DiplomaPdfDataGenerator(diplomaData).generateOtherPagesPdf());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new DiplomaPdfFileProducerException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

and this is the result:

[image: title page, margin is changed]

[image: overlap]

Comment: What do `DiplomaPdfDataGenerator.generateFirstPagePdf()` and `DiplomaPdfDataGenerator.generateOtherPagesPdf()` return? And how do you generate your headers? And what are the values of those `DefaultPdfDocumentSettings` constants? Other than that the code looks like the code in my answer which does work like expected. Thus,  something is special about those objects or mechanics.

Comment: It worked. The generateFirstPagePdf() and generateOtherPagesPdf() return Paragraph/Element.  I just didn't notice the difference because DefaultPdfDocumentSettings.TOP_MARGIN is 20. I changed the top margin to 60 and I noticed the difference

Comment: Great! I was starting to wonder what those methods could return to make the result ignore the margins... ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just tried what you described:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("test");
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    builder.append(" test");
String test = builder.toString();

try (   OutputStream pdfStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(RESULT_FOLDER, "ChangingMargins.pdf")))
{
    Document pdfDocument = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
    PdfWriter.getInstance(pdfDocument, pdfStream);
    pdfDocument.open();

    for (int m = 0; m < pdfDocument.getPageSize().getWidth() / 2; m += 100)
    {
        pdfDocument.setMargins(m, m, 100, 100);
        pdfDocument.newPage();
        pdfDocument.add(new Paragraph(test));
    }

    pdfDocument.close();
}
```

*([ChangeMargins.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/content/ChangeMargins.java#L41) method `testChangingMargins`)*

The result:

[image: Screenshot]

Thus, considering your item 1: Yes, iText can *have a different margin on a specific page.*

The OP wondered in a comment:

> how about top and bottom margin? :/

For this I changed the loop above to:

```
    for (int m = 0; m < pdfDocument.getPageSize().getWidth() / 2 && m < pdfDocument.getPageSize().getHeight() / 2; m += 100)
    {
        pdfDocument.setMargins(m, m, m, m);
        pdfDocument.newPage();
        pdfDocument.add(new Paragraph(test));
    }
```

And the result:

[image: Screenshot]

Thus, different top and bottom margins work, too.

---

Considering your issue 2 whether *there any way to prevent header and element from overlapping*: Usually they do not overlap.

Comment: how about top and bottom margin? :/

Comment: Cf. my edit, after the obvious change vertical margins change, too.

Comment: I edited my post to add some line of code and screenshot of what happens after adding content

Comment: I have a similar Problem, but I am adding just one Paragraph spanning multiple pages, that has to have a different top margin only on page 1, can one achieve that aswell?

Comment: @Joschka you can try to do that using page events.